# Why is the equation $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, units, mass-energy, dimensional-analysis

The equation [$E=mc^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) never made any sense to me.

c is a constant (speed of light), therefore c squared is also a constant. We're not specifying any units so surely the equation should be reduced to this:

e = m

Why include the "c squared" part?

Comment: Setting $c=1$ **is** specifying units.

Comment: @WillO Not entirely - you still have to choose the units of mass-energy.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean to say, all constants are equal and therefore = 1 ? The speed of light is a number *with unit*: $c = 3 \cdot 10^8 \text{m/s}$.

Comment: You may want to read Einstein's paper "Does the inertial of a body depend on its energy content" which is the basis of the formula.

Comment: @WillO Setting $c=1$ specifies a compatibility condition between units for length and time, but it does not fully specify units. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303457/units-in-special-relativity/488286#488286

Comment: @Bob D. I would strongly discourage reading papers written by classics unless you want history of science. Much better to read a respected modern text-book on the subject - it would have retained the good bits and dropped the unnecessary stuff (meant for specialists). I would suggest Goldstein "Classical Mechanics", or Barut "Electrodynamics and Classical Theory of Fields and Particles".

Comment: @WillO Yes, but only for one of the variables. I can still specify mass in kilograms and energy in "Einsteins".

Comment: @ChiftiSaidi - No, you can't (express energy in einsteins). The einstein is not a unit of energy. It is a mole of photons, the energy of which depends on frequency. Aside: As a unit, einstein is lowercase. The same goes for newtons, kelvins, ohms, volts, amperes, pascals, becquerels, curies, etc. Having one's name lowercased in the form of a unit is one of the pinnacle forms of praise in physics and chemistry.

Comment: @DavidHammen The OP was likely unaware that the einstein is an already-used unit.

Answer (score 7):

The equation $E=m$ is only valid in **one** particular class of systems of units. Namely, whenever your system of units is constructed such that the speed of light $c$ is unitless and $c=1$, then $E=m$ is valid, because, in those systems, *mass and energy are expressed in the same units*.

On the other hand, the equation $E=mc^2$ is valid for **all** systems of units, because it accounts for the case where $c$ has units and also accounts for systems of units where the numerical value of $c$ is not equal to $1$.

For example, if you were using SI units, where energy is specified in joules (meaning kg m$^2$/s$^2$) and where mass is specified in kg, then $E=m$ wouldn't make any sense at all - the units don't match up! It would be like saying "$3$ seconds is the same as $5$ liters": there are some contexts in which that would make sense, but only *after* you had established some kind of **direct conversion** between seconds and liters. (Setting $c=1$ establishes just such a conversion, which is why $E=m$ works and why mass and energy are specified in the same units for any system where $c=1$.) In contrast, $E=mc^2$ works perfectly, because a mass (kg) multiplied by a squared speed (m$^2$/s$^2$) gives you precisely the right units for energy, and so the two sides can be sensibly equated.

$E=mc^2$ is the more general expression, and $E=m$ is a special case for particular systems of units.

That said, $E=mc^2$ (where $m$ is the rest mass of the object*) only applies to objects that aren't moving. The most general expression relating the mass and energy of a point particle moving with momentum $p$ is:

$$E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$$

---

*Historically, there is a concept called *relativistic mass* which is defined differently, but this is not often taught in the modern era. Nowadays, we usually think of mass in relativity as synonymous with rest mass, but we still use the term "rest mass" to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: If you're saying that "we can adjust c to fit our units" then why don't we adjust those units instead?

eg. We could say E = m, where m is in kilograms and E is in "Einsteins"

Comment: An Einstein would be a huge amount of energy, about 90 quadrillion joules. SI units have been chosen to fit the lengths, masses, times, energies, etc. that are we encounter in daily life.

Comment: @G.Smith An einstein would be huge, yes, but so is "c2" and many other physical constants. Ensteins would only be used by atomic scientists, I doubt anybody would encounter them in the supermarket.

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's original formulation was Energy (in ergs) = mass (in grams) x c (speed of light) squared in centimetres per second. Ergs have fallen out of favour, so they probably use different units nowadays. This site keeps correcting my English spelling, not withstanding the fact that the true authentic English is from England, just as real champagne is from France.

Comment: Ergs, grams and centimeters were all defined before "E=mc2" so it would be a remarkable coincidence if that were true.

Comment: @ChiftiSaidi - It's not a coincidence. Any system of units in which the kinetic energy of an object moving at much less than the speed of light is given by $E=\frac12mv^2$ will result in $E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$. Note well: This does **not** work with energy in BTUs, mass in short tons, and speed in knots.

Comment: @DavidHammen It's not a matter of units. It doesn't follow at all that the energy required to move a weight a certain distance should be directly related to the energy locked up inside an atomic nucleus.

Comment: @Chifti - It's completely a matter of units. In a consistent set of units, energy has units of mass times velocity squared and Newtonian kinetic energy is $\frac12 mv^2$. Both cgs (centimeter-grams-seconds) and SI are consistent sets of units. With regard to energy locked up inside an atomic nucleus, relativity says nothing. Special and general relativity are classical (i.e., non-quantum) theories.

Comment: [English invented champagne](https://www.decanter.com/wine-news/taittinger-english-champagne-invented-408486/).